# Sending files over bluetooth using PyBluez and PyOBEX

Tags: python, bluetooth, pybluez

I'm trying to send a file from my laptop(win10) to my mobile(android) over bluetooth. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42440694/14259273) and I'm doing the same with python 3.6

I'm using [PyOBEX Python 3 Package](https://github.com/BlackLight/PyOBEX) and this is what I've tried.

```
import sys
from PyOBEX.client import Client
from bluetooth import *

addr = '60:7E:DD:A7:42:43' 


print("Searching for OBEX service on {}".format(addr))
services = find_service(address=addr, name=b'OBEX Object Push\x00')
if len(services) == 0:
    sys.exit()


first_match = services[0]
port = first_match["port"]

client = Client(addr, port)
client.connect()
client.put("test.txt", "Hello world\n")
client.disconnect()
```

When I run this, the device is discovered but it doesn't establish a connection or send files. This is the error it gives

[image]

I tried messing around with the PyOBEX package by changing the type of data returned by *socket_.recv* to **str** but it gives me another error,
[image]

I'm stuck and I have never worked with bluetooth or sockets before. Any help is appreciated

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text.

Comment: it seems this module is for Python 2 (which treats `string` as `bytes`) and it needs changes to work with Python 3 (which doesn't treat `string` as `bytes`). For example `socket_.rect(...)` may need `socket_.rect(...).decode()` and `struct,unpack(self.format, data)` may need `struct,unpack(self.format, data.encode())`. Shortly: someone mess with `data` - sometimes it is srting, sometimes it is bytes.